# Access AutoExec for DetectIdleTime breaks other code

Tags: vba, ms-access, macros

I have a data base using Access 2007-2010 and I have a AutoExec that auto starts to start detecting when and if a user leaves the front end open, it will close after an hour.  I used the Detect User Idle Time from Microsoft website https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192885.aspx and at the end of it I had it save and close the program instead of how they did it.  The problem I am having is that it breaks all other code that was written in vba. I have another form with buttons that copy entrys in a table and change what the user wants, and all of them worked until I added this macro. When I comment out all of my code so that it does nothing and I leave the macro the same to start up,  it still breaks the other code.  Im not sure if it is because I have the macro start a form with the code to detect idle time that is constantly running causing everything else to partially work.

[My Macro that is named "AutoExec"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wclu4.png)

Here is my code for the detecting the idle time

```
    Option Compare Database

    Sub Form_Timer()

     ' IDLEMINUTES determines how much idle time to wait for before
     ' running the IdleTimeDetected subroutine.
     Const IDLEMINUTES = 60

     Static PrevControlName As String
     Static PrevFormName As String
     Static ExpiredTime

     Dim ActiveFormName As String
     Dim ActiveControlName As String
     Dim ExpiredMinutes

     On Error Resume Next

     ' Get the active form and control name.

     ActiveFormName = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
     If Err Then
        ActiveFormName = "No Active Form"
        Err = 0
     End If

     ActiveControlName = Screen.ActiveControl.Name
        If Err Then
        ActiveControlName = "No Active Control"
        Err = 0
     End If

    Me.CurFormtxt = ActiveFormName

     ' Record the current active names and reset ExpiredTime if:
     '    1. They have not been recorded yet (code is running
     '       for the first time).
     '    2. The previous names are different than the current ones
     '       (the user has done something different during the timer
     '        interval).
     If (PrevControlName = "") Or (PrevFormName = "") _
       Or (ActiveFormName <> PrevFormName) _
       Or (ActiveControlName <> PrevControlName) Then
        PrevControlName = ActiveControlName
        PrevFormName = ActiveFormName
        ExpiredTime = 0
     Else
        ' ...otherwise the user was idle during the time interval, so
        ' increment the total expired time.
        ExpiredTime = ExpiredTime + Me.TimerInterval
     End If

     ' Does the total expired time exceed the IDLEMINUTES?
     ExpiredMinutes = (ExpiredTime / 1000) / 60
     Me.TimeInactivitytxt = ExpiredMinutes
     If ExpiredMinutes >= IDLEMINUTES Then
        ' ...if so, then reset the expired time to zero...
        ExpiredTime = 0

        ' ...and close the program
        Application.Quit acQuitSaveAll
     End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: What is the `TimerInterval` setting of the hidden form? I must say, I use `Form_Timer` for a few things, and it has never broken anything.

Comment: The TimerInterval is used to specify the interval, in milliseconds, between timer events on a form.  I got this from the MS website and just changed the bottom to close the database instead of what they had done. Also could you please post your Form_Timer, I would like to see it.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I know what `TimerInterval` is. :) I meant: which value for TimerInterval does your form have? i.e. how often is your sub called?

Comment: Ohh and I had it set to 1000 so every second it would update, I then changed it to 5000 for every 5 seconds to run and what I found out is if I use my other code through buttons, they will work as long as i dont run or hit the buttons on the 5th sec.  so it breaks when the desired interval runs the code even if there is no code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing around I found a work around for this problem.  What I did was made a new method found below where i call it in my other methods twice.  This is so it shuts off the timer first, does what it has to do and calls this again to re-enable the timer.  only down side is I have to add it to all the methods that need it.

```
Private Sub TimerIntervalSwitch()

'MsgBox "TimerIntervalSwitch was called"
'To turn off and on the timer on the form DetectIdleTime
If Form_DetectIdleTime.TimerInterval = 1000 Then
    Form_DetectIdleTime.TimerInterval = 0
    MsgBox "Timer Off"
ElseIf (Form_DetectIdleTime.TimerInterval = 0) Then
    Form_DetectIdleTime.TimerInterval = 1000
    MsgBox "Timer On"

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a well-known issue. The timer breaks in and may disrupt what the user is currently working with.

Sadly, there is no way around it, and I have wondered for years why such code still is recommended. It will cause nothing but trouble - as you have seen.

Comment: That is very upsetting.  The only reason I added this was because I needed to compact and repair the database and I cant seem to get every one off or it is corrupt and think everyone is on when no one is.  I am going to try and copy the data base, compact and repair it and send out a new front end that is connected to the new back end. This is the best I have thought of